# Reflection not working on android release apk. Even with proguard/minify disabled

Tags: java, android, reflection, proguard

Currently I'm facing an odd issue that the release apk of my app throws NoSuchFieldExceptions. It works fine on a debug apk.

The fields I am trying to get are android.widget packaged.
I have also made efforts with enabling proguard too and setting configurations in the proguard.pro file

Here's the exception regardless.

java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class java.lang.Class cannot access  field android.widget.ProgressBar com.trinitcore.localtrade.LoginActivity.o of class java.lang.Class

Gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.trinitcore.localtrade"
        minSdkVersion  15 //15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.7
        sourceCompatibility 1.7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch:library:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:materialize:0.9.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.7.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter:1.6.1@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.1@aar"
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.3.original@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:meteocons-typeface:1.1.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:1.7.22.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:weather-icons-typeface:2.0.10.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:typeicons-typeface:2.0.7.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:entypo-typeface:1.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:devicon-typeface:2.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:foundation-icons-typeface:3.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:ionicons-typeface:2.0.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.lusfold.spinnerloading:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.3'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.0'
    compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'

    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IllegalAccessException means it can see the variable/method, but that it can't access it because its private (or because its protected and this isn't the same package).  This isn't a case of reflection not working, its a common bug that without reflection wouldn't compile.

You can change the visibility of the variable/method at runtime using reflection and then access it, but its not recommended.  Its better to add a public method that does what you need, to prevent the possibility of changing data in ways the class wasn't written to accept.

Comment: Amazingly your answer works. Setting the variables that the reflection wants to access to public fixed the problem. But I'm still confused as to why this only occurs in the release version of the app and not in the debug version?

Comment: @user256272 did you ever figure out why this happens in release and not debug?