# android drawables and animations not showing in released version

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable, android-proguard

I am trying to animate circles (`ShapeDrawables`)  on a View's canvas. The debug version of the app runs without issue. However, the released version does not show the circles or the animation. I have tried the following the following in Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    config {
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.TestInterface.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
    debug {
        jniDebuggable false
    }
} }
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2' }
```

with the following flags in my `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-dontobfuscate
-keep class android.support.graphics.drawable.** { *; }
-keep class android.graphics.drawable.** { *; }
-keep class android.animation.** { *; }
```

I checked the APK analyzer to ensure that the getter and setter on my circle (wrapped `ShapedDrawable`) were not obfuscated. I even used the APK analyzer to generate the proguard keep rules.

When running the Release Build ONLY, Logcat shows `W/PropertyValuesHolder: Method getDiameter() with type null not found on target class class xxx.xxx.xxx.CircleAnimator$CirleHolder`. But I checked the APK Analyzer and these aren't obfuscated...

Code for adding animation is shown below:

```
private void newCircleAnimation(){
    int size = circles.size();
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(circles.get(size - newAnimationCount), "diameter", getEndSize());
    animator.setDuration(getAnimationDuration());
    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            CircleHolder tempCircle = (CircleHolder) ((ObjectAnimator) animation).getTarget();
            // Have to check first in case it was removed with reset()
            if (circles.contains(tempCircle)){
                circles.remove(tempCircle);
            }
            animationCount--;
        }
    });
    animator.start();
    animationCount++;
}
```

I'm not sure what else would be different from debug to release version. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

My problem was using `package private` getters and setters. I changed them to `public`. I'm still not sure why this only happens in release, not debug.

I found the answer from here:
[Reflection not working on release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525867/reflection-not-working-on-android-release-apk-even-with-proguard-minify-disable)